# Call a function which is a result of another function call

Tags: function, lambda, erlang

I have a function which takes two arguments and returns a function with arity 1:

```
make_fun(A, B) -> 
    fun(C) -> 
        A + B + C
    end.
```

I use the function above to create a function and then apply it to an argument like this:

```
Fun = make_fun(1,2),
Result = Fun(3).
```

So that `Result = 6` after this.

The question is: Is there a way to do the same thing without storing the function in `Fun`?

Something like this would be ideal but doesn't seem to work:

```
Result = make_fun(1,2)(3).
```

Comment: `(make_fun(1, 2))(3)`?

Comment: @Dogbert Yes, that works, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
make_fun(A, B) ->
      fun(C) ->
          A + B + C
      end.
```

Just put `make_fun` in parentheses :

```
(make_fun(1, 2))(3).
```

Answer (score -2):

How about This ?

Result = Fun(make_fun(1,2)).

Comment: You may have misread the question, I'm trying to not use Fun at all